# How to attach Bootstrap tooltip to Clojurescript Reagent component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, clojurescript, reagent

Here's a component I'm rendering at the end of each row of a table.  The tooltip portion is not working.

How can I attach Bootstrap tooltips to each component after it renders?

```
(defn edit-button-component []
    (fn [attrs]
        ^{:component-did-mount #(.tooltip ($ %) (clj->js {:title "Test"}))}
        [:button.btn.btn-default attrs
        [:span.glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil]]))
```

Comment: any errors in console? Did you try to prn in function to make sure component-did-mount fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @myguidingstar explanation on accessing `js/$` and the DOM node, it seems your metadata was not at the right place. It needs to be on the function, not the vector.

Here is an implementation that works for me:

```
(def tooltip
  ^{:component-did-mount #(.tooltip (js/$ (reagent.core/dom-node %)))}
  (fn [message]
    [:img.help {:src "img/help.png", :data-placement "bottom", :title message}]))
```

Also make sure jquery is loaded before your app.js in your html file.

Answer (score 3):

Where is the symbol `$` from? If it's from `jayq` library then it's fine. If it's plain javascript jQuery, then you need `js/$` instead.

the argument `%` to the anonymous function associated with `:component-did-mount` is often named `this` and it's a React component, not a DOM object. To get the equivalent DOM node to feed jQuery `$` selector, use `reagent.core/dom-node`. Something like:

```
($ (reagent.core/dom-node %))
```

Btw, `(clj->js {:title "Test"})` can be better written as `#js {:title "Test"}`